# How to set canvas origin to center in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When I draw a circle on fabricjs canvas it always appears on bottom right corner even though I set the coordinates to center. How can I make the circle draw  center of the canvas?

```
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
         top: 300,
         left: 300,
         radius: 100
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set drawing origin of the circle object to center, using **[`originX`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#originX)** and **[`originY`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#originY)** property.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
   top: 100,
   left: 100,
   radius: 50,
   originX: 'center',
   originY: 'center'
});

canvas.add(circle);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.14/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! but, if I were to set different origins? will this work?

Comment: Yes, it will. You can set `x` and `y` origin as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You have centerObject().

```
     canvas.add(oImg)
     canvas.centerObject(circle);
     canvas.renderAll();
```

That sets your circle in the center of the canvas.